# any beautifier for javascript could align = and :

Tags: javascript

```
var tom = 5,
 jack = 6,
 jason = 7;

var m = {
  tom : 'tom',
  jack : 'jack',
  jason: 'jason'
}
```

want beautify to:

```
var tom   = 'tom',
    jack  = 'jack',
    jason = 'jason',
    other, stand, vars;

var map = {
  tom   : 'tom',
  jack  : 'jack',
  jason : 'jason'
}
```

Comment: IMO, that's not too beautiful.

Comment: how about now, I modified the var name like normal code.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a javascript-based tool that did this for EditPlus a while back:

http://editplus.info/wiki/User_Tools#Fix_Code_Spacing

The specific input/output is for a windows-based system on stdin and stdout, but the formatting code can easily be adapted to run in node if you prefer.  You can then send input from whatever editor you're using to it as many editors allow you to run filters through external tools.

And my 2cent personal preference:

```
var tom = 'tom',
   jack = 'jack',
  jason = 'jason',
  other, stand, vars;

var map = {
    tom : 'tom',
   jack : 'jack',
  jason : 'jason'
}
```

Comment: um, or you could :)  I gave you the formatting code, the only thing that needs to be changed are the calls to `stdIn` and `stdOut`

Comment: I ported it to node, works, but has bug in indent. there is no left space for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Try NotePad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: The very purpose most coders work on NotePad++ editor is its alignment or pretty printer option.

Comment: @openingbrace notepad++ is a baby step up from notepad.

Answer (score 0):

dont know what u actually require but the same can be done in ecilpse IDE JS files `select all --> ctrl + I`